# Google analytics embedded external SWF

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, flash, actionscript-2

Here is my problem. I have a SWF file that I want to do some event tracking on in Google analytics. It has to go into a CMS and I am unable to insert the google tracking code on that page.

I am wondering if there is a method I can use perhaps using an external site and embedding the SWF in order to make calls to the Google Analytics on a remote server and track the events?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a component for doing Google Analytics event tracking from within the swf, without having to insert tracking code in the page:

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/flashTrackingIntro.html

Comment: I should of added that I am looking for an as2 solution. I wasn't expecting the answer to be version specific :( shame because that looks awesome.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to this externally, using the External Interface or getURL methods inside flash.

They can call Javascript functions from the HTML page that contains the .swf embedded.

All you have to do is create a function that runs the code snipped from Google Analytics, and call that function from within your flash, as simple as:

```
getURL("javascript:Your_Function_Here");
```

Augusto Roselli - WebAnalytics - [dp6](http://www.dp6.com.br)

Comment: this relies on the javascript being included on the same page as the embedded SWF, I need to call the tracking on a remote server as I can't put it on the same page as the embedded SWF

Comment: Then it's unfortunately impossible, Google Analytics uses first party cookies, so anyway you cannot call for the tracking of one page from a remote server.